# Path and File location in the NoxPlayer emulator

Tags: files, noxplayer

Recently I installed the NoxPlayer emulator on my PC. Almost all APK ask for file permissions. By default, NoxPlayer is installed in the `C:\` drive. I allowed all APK for file access permission in NoxPlayer.

Where can I find the files?

Moreover, in some cases, I need to access pictures and files.

In which path should I put files so that they can be accessed by Android applications?

Comment: Usually emulators are like a computer inside your computer. Every app running inside can only see what is inside. The file system of Windows is not seen and thus it doesn't matter where you installed it to in file system. The apps are asking for file permission on Android level inside the emulator.

Comment: Okay. Where should I put my files or images in the computer so that they can be accessed by android apps installed in emulator (NoxPLayer)?

Comment: The official site has this blog article: [How to share/copy files between NoxPlayer and your computer](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-sharecopy-files-between-nox-app-player-and-your-computer/). Could you try it?

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. Yes, this one seems helpful for me. Thank you very much